# Embedding IE in a window under CE

Tags: c, winapi, com, windows-ce

i'm writing a WinCE700 application that embeds a IE window.
If i run the IE (and then close it) the iesample, my application runs.
If I run the application before IE i receive a COM error 0x80040154 in the following call:

```
hRes = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_WebBrowser, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC, &IID_IWebBrowser2, (void **)&webBrowser2);
```

My guess is that IE registers something: how can i register the IID_IWebBrowser2 interface?
I searched in the registry of the WinCE device and i found the CLSID items.

Comment: I'd try `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` instead of `CLSCTX_INPROC`, as IE is typically run out-of-process in WinCE.

Comment: As stated in the documentation, the only valid value is CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER. CLSCTX_INPROC contains this value. Anyway I checked with each of these values but i always receive the 'Interface not registered' error.

Comment: Other clue: if I use CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER i'm not able to run the application. If I use CLSCTX_INPROC my application is able to run after a IE run.

Comment: Try the code at the bottom of [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/291231d9-d52f-4628-9dbd-ea2200aee245/the-best-kept-secret-webbrowser-interface?forum=vssmartdevicesnative).  It appears that you need to go through some QI magic (which surprises me, as it's a violation of COM identity).

Comment: No way. I modified the code on the bottom of the link (some '&'s were missing...). I also had to modify the code like 'hr = pUnk->lpVtbl->QueryInterface(pUnk, &IID_IOleObject, (LPVOID *)(&pObject));'. Anyway i always have the original error.

Comment: Not sure whether you meant that it works, or that it's still generating the same HRESULT.

Comment: Same HRESULT = 0x80040154 but = 0x0 after the IE run -- Note: when equal S_OK, i'm not able to find the ieframe.dll file on the device even if it is present on the list of the loaded modules I see in the VS debug output ... (????)

Comment: Found! The ieframe.dll was located in a subdirectory on a external usb key i'm using to start the device in debug mode. Ie was able to find but not my application. Anyway I added the ieframe.dll into the Windows folder and the application has no more problem.